# How does one escape an apostrophe in db2 sql

Tags: sql, db2, escaping

I'm looking for the db2 equivalent of T-SQL's:

```
INSERT INTO People (Surname) VALUES ('O''Hara');
```

Comment: Can you post up the DB2 version and the SQL error you get?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use two apostrophes `''` to get a single apostrophe on DB2 too, according to the [DB2 Survival Guide](http://www.michael-thomas.com/tech/db2/db2_survival_guide.htm). Isn't that working for you?

Comment: I was sure I'd done that before on DB2 but don't have a DB2 instance to hand! Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 8):

*Brabster* is correct. You are supposed to escape `'` with `''`
So to insert O'Hara , you will have to write O''Hara
Excerpt from: 
http://www.michael-thomas.com/tech/db2/db2_survival_guide.htm

> Escape character.
>
> To insert a single quote, use 2 single
>   quotes ( '' ).  To insert pet's use
>   the following pet''s.
>   *Example:*   insert into MYTABLE (question,answer) values ('What is
>   your pet''s name?','blacky') `

Comment: this is not working for me: `com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-798, SQLSTATE=428C9, SQLERRMC=ID, DRIVER=4.13.127, query: INSERT INTO students (dob, first_name, id, last_name) VALUES (DATE '1965-12-01', 'Jim', 1, 'O''Connor''s')`, any idea?

Comment: @ipolevoy I thing the problem with your query is not the last_name but the DATE at the left of the String '1965-12-01'. I confirm I was able to update a col with 'O''Connor''s' in a DB2 Linux.

Answer (score 2):

just make it simple.

Keep your query in the single quotes ('). and where ever you are using qoutes, make it double.
for e.g. u want to insert ......   I'm fine. There's an answer.

in SQL we need to give .......    'I''m fine. There''s an answer.'

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to insert into DB2 a regex expression for an email address. I thought I had to escape all characters as outlined at the proceeding link, but escaping only the single quote contained within the regex seems to be all I needed to escape to get it properly inserted into the database:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ts.doc/doc/c0059609.html

Comment: That page is from the part of the manual that covers the Db2 Text Search feature (see it’s position in the Table of Contents). This is a separate add-on with separate syntax and functions. That page does not apply to SQL functions or general syntax.

Comment: For regex, you do need to escape regex special characters however. E.g. to match a [ you would need to use \[  in the regex pattern