# What is the simplest way to migrate data from MySQL to DB2

Tags: db2, mysql, db2-luw

I need to migrate data from MySQL to DB2. Both DBs are up and running.

I tried to `mysqldump` with `--no-create-info --extended-insert=FALSE --complete-insert` and with a few changes on the output (e.g. change ` to `"`), I get to a satisfactory result but sometimes I have weird exceptions, like 
`does not have an 
ending string delimiter.  SQLSTATE=42603`

Ideally I would want to have a routine that is as general as possible, but as an example here, let's say I have a DB2 table that looks like:

```
db2 => describe table "mytable"

                                Data type                     Column
Column name                     schema    Data type name      Length     Scale Nulls
------------------------------- --------- ------------------- ---------- ----- ------
id                              SYSIBM    BIGINT                       8     0 No    
name                            SYSIBM    VARCHAR                    512     0 No    

  2 record(s) selected.
```

Its MySQL counterpart being

```
mysql> describe mytable;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(512) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Let's assume the DB2 and MySQL databases are called `mydb`.

Now, if I do

```
mysqldump -uroot mydb mytable --no-create-info --extended-insert=FALSE --complete-insert | # mysldump, with options (see below): # do not output table create statement # one insert statement per record# ouput table column names
sed -n -e '/^INSERT/p' |     # only keep lines beginning with "INSERT"
sed 's/`/"/g' |              # replace ` with "
sed 's/;$//g' |              # remove `;` at end of insert query
sed "s/\\\'/''/g"            # replace `\'` with `''` , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442205/how-does-one-escape-an-apostrophe-in-db2-sql and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369314/why-does-sed-require-3-backslashes-for-a-regular-backslash
```

, I get:

```
INSERT INTO "mytable" ("id", "name") VALUES (1,'record 1')
INSERT INTO "mytable" ("id", "name") VALUES (2,'record 2')
INSERT INTO "mytable" ("id", "name") VALUES (3,'record 3')
INSERT INTO "mytable" ("id", "name") VALUES (4,'record 4')
INSERT INTO "mytable" ("id", "name") VALUES (5,'" "" '' ''''  \"\"  ')
```

This ouput can be used as a DB2 query and it works well.

Any idea on how to solve this more efficiently/generally? Any other suggestions?

Comment: You would need to share how to imported the data into DB2, some data samples and the CREATE TABLE or schema for us to help

Comment: @data_henrik added some additional info, hope it helps

Comment: Why don't you dump into a .csv and then use import or load with DB2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having played around a bit I came with the following routine which I believe to be fairly general, robust and scalable.

1 Run the following command:

```
mysqldump -uroot mydb mytable --no-create-info --extended-insert=FALSE --complete-insert | # mysldump, with options (see below): # do not output table create statement # one insert statement per record# ouput table column names
sed -n -e '/^INSERT/p' |     # only keep lines beginning with "INSERT"
sed 's/`/"/g' |              # replace ` with "
sed -e 's/\\"/"/g' |         # replace `\"` with `#` (mysql escapes double quotes)
sed "s/\\\'/''/g" > out.sql  # replace `\'` with `''` , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442205/how-does-one-escape-an-apostrophe-in-db2-sql and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369314/why-does-sed-require-3-backslashes-for-a-regular-backslash
```

Note: here unlike in the question `;` are not being removed.

2 upload the file to DB2 server
`scp out.sql user@myserver:out.sql`

3 run queries from the file
`db2 -tvsf /path/to/query/file/out.sql`